# Storing `nargs=3` as multiple variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I want to be able to run both those commands:

```py
python3 arguments.py --option1 reference
python3 arguments.py --option2 a b c
```

I have this code, which works:

```py
import argparse


"""
" Parse arguments
"""
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--option1', help="Do stuff with the one argument.")
parser.add_argument('--option2', nargs=3, help="Do stuff with all three arguments.")
  # https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.option1:
    print(args.option1) # will contain a string
if args.option2:
    print(len(args.option2), "arguments:")
    print(args.option2) # will contain a list
    print(args.option2[0])
```

But then I have to use `args.option2[0]`, `args.option2[1]` and `args.option2[2]` to access the values, which is poorly readable.

**Using argparse,** is there a way to do this?

1. Store them as three separate variables. To access them, respectively, as `argparse.audio`, `argparse.text`, `argparse.output` variables?
2. Document the order of those arguments in the code itself (so that they show in `python3 arguments.py --help`.)
3. Check their values to make sure they are, respectively, a path to a file, a string and a path to a file.

Comment: Drop argparse, use [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/)

Comment: I've never actually used it, but this looks like a good application for `argparse`'s subparser feature.  You'd add a subparser triggered by `"-option2"`, then you could add your `audio`, `text`, and `output` arguments to the subparser as positional arguments.  You'd have all of the usual options for validating and documenting those arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python unpacking:

```
a, b, c = args.option2
```

And for the help enhancement:

```
metavar=('a','b','c')
```

See the docs.

Check the types, file path, dir etc yourself after parsing.  You don't get bonus points for doing everything in the parser.  Filenames are just strings; it's what you (can) do with them that differs, such as open for reading (requires an existing file) versus open for writing (creates a new file).

You could even do

```
args.a, args.b, arg.c = args.option2
```

(if you need to pass the `args` namespace around, rather than 3 individual variables.)  Once you have parsed the input, the rest is standard Python.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar